# Python - Passing a list with elements, but I only get the first element in the list

Tags: python, pass-by-reference, mergesort

I have a file with 100000 lines that contains data in the following manner:

```
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
22  377 1   878887116
244 51  2   880606923
```

where the first column stand for ID. I wanted to apply a merge sort algorithm on ID, so I took a merge sort algorithm from [geeksforgeeks](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort/) in C++ and converted it to Python.

```
import sys
sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)


class Data:
    id = 0
    n1 = 0
    rate = 0
    n2 = 0


def main():
    d = []
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            obj = Data()
            obj.id, obj.n1, obj.rate, obj.n2 = map(int, line.split())
            d.append(obj)

    mergesort(d, 0, 100000-1)
    printarray(d, 100000)


def mergesort(d, l, r):
    if l < r:
        m = int(l + int((r - l) / 2))
        mergesort(d, l, m)
        mergesort(d, m + 1, r)
        merge(d, l, m, r)


def merge(d, l, m, r):
    b1 = int(m - l + 1)
    b2 = int(r - m)

    left = []
    right = []

    for i in range(b1):
        left.append(d[l + i])

    for i in range(b2):
        right.append(d[l + i])

    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = l

    while i < b1 and j < b2:
        if left[i].id <= right[j].id:
            d[k].id = left[i].id
            d[k].n1 = left[i].n1
            d[k].rate = left[i].rate
            d[k].n2 = left[i].n2
            i = i + 1

        else:
            d[k].id = right[j].id
            d[k].n1 = right[j].n1
            d[k].rate = right[j].rate
            d[k].n2 = right[j].n2
            j = j + 1
        k = k + 1

    while i < b1:
        d[k].id = left[i].id
        d[k].n1 = left[i].n1
        d[k].rate = left[i].rate
        d[k].n2 = left[i].n2
        i = i + 1
        k = k + 1

    while j < b2:
        d[k].id = right[j].id
        d[k].n1 = right[j].n1
        d[k].rate = right[j].rate
        d[k].n2 = right[j].n2
        j = j + 1
        k = k + 1


def printarray(d, size):
    with open('output.txt', 'w') as f:
        for i in range(0, size):
            f.write('%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t\n' % (d[i].id, d[i].n1, d[i].rate, d[i].n2))

main()
```

The problem is when I pass my list of objects "d" to the mergesort function, and try to print the first and second elements of the list, like this:

```
def mergesort(d, l, r):
    print('%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t\n' % (d[0].id, d[0].n1, d[0].rate, d[0].n2))
    print('%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t\n' % (d[1].id, d[1].n1, d[1].rate, d[1].n2))
    if l < r:
        m = int(l + int((r - l) / 2))
        mergesort(d, l, m)
        mergesort(d, m + 1, r)
        merge(d, l, m, r)
```

It prints:

```
196 242 3 881250949
196 242 3 881250949
```

However when I tried the same in my main function, it showed correct results.
So when I pass my list to the other functions, it only contains the first element "*196 242 3 881250949*".

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do with this "mergesort" stuff but it really looks like reinventing the proverbial SquareWheel(tm) when Python already has one of the most optimized sorting algorithm builtin...

Answer (score 0):

In Python it's very recommended to use the built-in functions. I'd convert the file to a list and then either use lambda or convert the list into a dict where the key is the ID and then use sort().

Answer (score 0):

Keeping it simple always pay:

```
def main():
    with open("input.csv") as f:
        rows = [
            tuple(int(x) for x in line.strip().split("\t")) 
            for line in f
            if line.strip()
            ]
    rows.sort()
    with open("output.csv", "w") as f:
        for row in rows:
            f.write("{}\n".format("\t".join(str(x) for x in row)))

main()


$ cat input.csv 
196 242 3   881250949
186 302 3   891717742
22  377 1   878887116
244 51  2   880606923

cat output.csv
22  377 1   878887116
186 302 3   891717742
196 242 3   881250949
244 51  2   880606923
```

Comment: I realize there are simpler ways to sort the file, but I need to sort it using the merge sort method. The problem I have is when I pass the list to my mergesort function, all the elements in the list become equal to the first element (196 242 3   881250949).

Comment: " I need to sort it using the merge sort method" => Why ? Is this homework ?

Comment: It is a task that was assigned to me by my professor. We want to check the difference in execution time for Merge Sort on big files between Python and Scala using Spark.

Comment: @Shaheen you should have mentioned it was homework. But with due respect to your professor such a benchmark makes no sense at all - no one would bother implementing his own sort algorithm when Python comes with one or the most optimized one (timsort) builtin.

Comment: Sorry, this is my first time asking a question on Stack Overflow. I know. The entire task does not make much sense because Python is an interpreted language in Spark and Scala is the native language, so definitely Scala will be faster. But I have to do it in hope to get a position as a Research Assistant.

Comment: What I mean here is that while obviously a pure python mergesort - even properly implemented by an experienced Python programmer - will probably be slower than anything optimized by the JRE jit compiler, it is practically a non-issue since that is typically where you either use the builtin C coded builtin function or use a C codec lib or (as a last resort) code tour own C coded extension. Being able to drop to a low level language for the performance sensitive parts is actually one of thé strength of the python ecosystem.

Comment: Actually Python is no more interpreted than Java - it is compiled to bytecode which is executed by a VM. The difference comes from Python being too dynamic to be easily optimized by a jit compiler.

Comment: But this is not really helping you, sorry... Im not going to try and understand your implementation but vgve you a couple hints : 1. if you have to code in Python do it the python way (use meaningful naming, use iterators, swap objects instead of mutating them in place etc), 2. make sure you understand how arguments are passed  forget about "by ref" and "by val" thats not how python works) and finally 3. use the debugger

Comment: I totally agree with you. Actually, Python is also easier to use than Scala and provides better visualization. I really appreciate your advise and the effort you took in order to help me. I am still new to Python and slowly trying to adjust to it. That's why my Python code looks more like a C++ code.